# Some doubts about what Factory does

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, factory, factory-pattern

I'm not really sure to understand completely the factory pattern.

Let's say I have a class `Customer` which has basically the following methods:

- `CreateCustomer` - static, creates a customer from scratch and adds it to the database,
- `LoadCustomer` - static, loads an instance of a `Customer` from the database,
- `KillCustomer` - **not** static, removes a customer from the database.

If I understand well,

1. `LoadCustomer` is a good candidate to be put into a factory class.
2. What about `CreateCustomer`? I suppose that **it may be put into a factory class**. Is that right? If not, the static `CreateCustomer` method will change the database state, *then call* `CustomerFactory.LoadCustomer`. IMHO, this is bad design: a given object don't have to know anything about her own factory.
3. `KillCustomer` seems to me **a very bad candidate** for a factory: it *acts* on an already created object, rather than creating one. On the other hand:

   - If a non-static method removes the customer from the database, the object (from which `KillCustomer` was called) still exists. This is quite strange to see **an object committing suicide on database level and still remaining on business level**. Calling `KillCustomer` from factory would be more reasonable on this level. For example, if the object is cached in application, the factory may remove it both from database and from cache.
   - Putting in different classes the method which creates an object and the method which removes it seems strange too. **Why can factory just build something, and never destroy what was built?**

Last but not least, let's say customers are cached in application. **Who is responsible to manage cache?** IMO, the factory must do it: it creates the objects, so it is a good candidate to choose if a new object with properties populated from database must be loaded, or if the object already exists in cache.

So, what's right and what's wrong in what I'm thinking about factory pattern?

Comment: On the subject of "committing suicide on database level and still remaining on business level" - you're right, this can lead to errors, especially if you don't clear object caches. But those errors could occur whether you have a factory or not, because the problem is you've done something destructive while some other part of your program is, loosely speaking, holding a reference. It's a shared-data problem (either two parts of the program sharing an object, or two objects sharing an entry in the DB). It's not a problem with how the objects are originally created.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: yes, you're right. I didn't thought about that.

Comment: Why was this made community wiki?

Comment: @Omnifarious: because I was not really sure if there is one single answer to my question.

Comment: When you make something community wiki, nobody gets any reputation increase when something is voted up.  It discourages people from answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory is not for building things.  It's for building things when you don't know exactly what you're going to build.  In my opinion, all of your methods are poor candidates for a factory.

Now, if you had a whole big bunch of different kinds of customers in an inheritance hierarchy rooted at `Customer` and some details about the data used to create a customer determined which kind of customer was made, then `CreateCustomer` would be a great candidate for a factory method.  The same with `LoadCustomer` since presumably you aren't completely sure exactly which sort of customer is being stored in the database.

But `KillCustomer` is still a bad candidate.  And that's because it should just be a virtual method.  Then it knows exactly which kind of customer it was called on.